# How run sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder on several columns?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

this code raise error:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

# Define categorical columns and mapping dictionary
categorical_cols = ['color', 'shape', 'size']
mapping = {'red': 0, 'green': 1, 'blue': 2, 'circle': 0, 'square': 1, 'triangle': 2, 'small': 0, 'medium': 1, 'large': 2}
cols = ['color','size']
# Define ColumnTransformer to preprocess categorical columns
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
  transformers=[
    ('orlEncdr_with_map', Pipeline(steps=[('orlEnc_with_map', OrdinalEncoder(categories=[list(mapping.keys())], dtype=int))]), cols),
  ])

# Load sample data
data = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'red'], 'shape': ['circle', 'square', 'triangle', 'triangle'], 'size': ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'medium']})

# Apply preprocessor to data
preprocessed_data = preprocessor.fit_transform(data)

# View preprocessed data
print(preprocessed_data)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_38148\1089712396.py in <module>
     18 
     19 # Apply preprocessor to data
---> 20 preprocessed_data = preprocessor.fit_transform(data)
     21 
     22 # View preprocessed data

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    673         self._validate_remainder(X)
    674 
--> 675         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    676 
    677         if not result:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted, column_as_strings)
    604         )
    605         try:
--> 606             return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
    607                 delayed(func)(
    608                     transformer=clone(trans) if not fitted else trans,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1046             # remaining jobs.
   1047             self._iterating = False
-> 1048             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1049                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1050 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    862                 return False
    863             else:
--> 864                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    865                 return True
    866 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    780         with self._lock:
    781             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 782             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    783             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    784             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    261         # change the default number of processes to -1
    262         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 263             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    264                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    265 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    261         # change the default number of processes to -1
    262         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 263             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    264                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    265 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    214     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    215         with config_context(**self.config):
--> 216             return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
    217 
    218 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    891     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    892         if hasattr(transformer, "fit_transform"):
--> 893             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    894         else:
    895             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    432             fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
    433             if hasattr(last_step, "fit_transform"):
--> 434                 return last_step.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    435             else:
    436                 return last_step.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step).transform(Xt)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    850         if y is None:
    851             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 852             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    853         else:
    854             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in fit(self, X, y)
    884 
    885         # `_fit` will only raise an error when `self.handle_unknown="error"`
--> 886         self._fit(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown, force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    887 
    888         if self.handle_unknown == "use_encoded_value":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in _fit(self, X, handle_unknown, force_all_finite)
     82         if self.categories != "auto":
     83             if len(self.categories) != n_features:
---> 84                 raise ValueError(
     85                     "Shape mismatch: if categories is an array,"
     86                     " it has to be of shape (n_features,)."

ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).
```

if you change it in this way it works:
`cols = ['size']`

How can I change it to works for several columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `mapping_dict` here. You have to replace it by a list of array to control the mapping.

```
# Define categorical columns and mapping dictionary
categorical_cols = ['color', 'shape', 'size']
cols = ['color', 'size']
cats = [['red', 'green', 'blue'], ['small', 'medium', 'large']]  # <- HERE

# Define ColumnTransformer to preprocess categorical columns
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
  transformers=[
    ('orlEncdr_with_map', Pipeline(steps=[('orlEnc_with_map', OrdinalEncoder(categories=cats, dtype=int))]), cols),
  ])
```

Output:

```
>>> preprocessed_data
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [0, 1]])
```

If you want to start from 1 instead of 0, you have to pad left:

```
cats = [[None, 'red', 'green', 'blue'], [None, 'small', 'medium', 'large']]
```

```
>>> preprocessed_data
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need the pipeline (within the `ColumnTransformer`), but it should work nevertheless.

Ordinal encoding works with this pared down `ColumnTransformer`:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('oe', 
                                      OrdinalEncoder(), 
                                      ['color', 'size'])
                                    ],
                       remainder='passthrough')

ct.fit_transform(data)
```

[Omit the `remainder='passthrough'` if you don't want 'shape' passed through.]

So it looks like there is a problem with the way you define the categories. Do you really need to do this? `OrdinalEncoder` defines the categories automatically based on the data seen in the `fit` method.

If, however, you do want to explicitly define the categories you can do so with a list of lists:

```
ct2=ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('oe',
                                     OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['green','blue','red'],
                                                                ['circle','square','triangle']]),
                                     ['color','shape'])
                                   ])
ct2.fit_transform(data)
```

Comment: yes, this sample doesn't need ColumnTransformer. I put it to make it similar to my main code.

Comment: I know it can define it automatically, but I need to be in my order, not a random order.